# How to Stop Spring boot applications console logs in var/log/messages file

Tags: linux, spring-boot, logging, log4j2, redhat

We're using spring boot and log4j2 for logging. We have specified the log path and it is working. But the same console logs are moving to var/log/messages file

Can someone please help me how to stop logging console logs in var/log/messages file.

Comment: Did you google it? If not found I think other forum is more suitble as superuser

Comment: Hi @user7294900, I've tried googling I was only getting either audit logs or log path setting for spring boot applications. Both of them are working for me. But I was not able to find how to stop the same console(application) logs from going into var/log/messages file. Is it stack Exchange you meant by other forum?

Comment: Edit: yes got it, super user in stack exchange. thanks:)

Comment: I guess you are starting the application as SystemD service. Can you share your `*.service` file? The default configuration is to send the standard output to **systemd-journald**, which also forwards it to **syslog**, which writes it to `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz, thanks for your response. Yes we're using systemd services to start the application. As per the .service file, we're using standardError=syslog    standardOutput=syslog.  And some info about jar path and time out and other stuff. But recently I tried changing syslog to some other path but still logs are going in messages file

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem here, and the solution was add the following parameter on the application.properties file:

```
logging.pattern.console=
```

Leaving 'blank' will stop the logging on

```
/var/log/messages
```

More details [Here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/logging-application-properties/)

Comment: While this would stop logging to /var/log/messages, wouldn't it essentially hide the logging altogether, so exceptions/issues would go unnoticed?